# How to avoid nested loops and speed up your program

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, nested-loops

I have written this program to evaluate the 10000 node dataset and with dynamic coverage (coverage means starting from one node how many nodes it can visit). It runs very slow and fails with the error `Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection` . I believe it is running out of memory.Any suggestions to speed it up and reduce the memory usage. I don't even run it on my system it runs on a cluster with 32 cores access. I run it in parallel using `foreach` loop and `doparallel` library.

```
#code for coverage graph
cover<- function(sampl){
#define the coverage parameter
co_nodes<-10
done<- 0
result<-matrix(nrow=10000,ncol =10000)
  if(co_nodes>1)
  {
    co_nodes<-co_nodes-1
    #loop to get all the elements.
    coverage_matrix<- NULL
    le<-unique(sampl$V2)
    le
    tl<-length(le)
    tl

    for(p in 1:tl)
    {
      message("main loop iteration:", p)
      #pick first node
      x<-le[p]
      x
      cv_matrix<- sampl[sampl$V1==x,]
      cv_matrix
      # ca   gets the new neibhour nodes from the matrix
      ca<-unique(cv_matrix$V2)
      ca
      chl<-length(ca)
if(chl==0)
{
next
}else
{
      for(i in (1:co_nodes))
      {
        message("coverage loop iteration:", i)
          #print("neibhour node")
          #print(c)
          # t gets nieghbours 
          t<-sampl[sampl$V1 %in% ca,]
cv_matrix<-rbind(cv_matrix,t)
          #message("ca:", ca)
          ca<-unique(t$V2)
          # print("ca after binding")
          #print(ca)
        message("exiting coverage loop iteration:", i )
        chl<-length(ca)
        if(chl==0)
        {
          break
        }
      }

cv_matrix$V1<- x
      coverage_matrix<-rbind(coverage_matrix,cv_matrix)
}
      }


    }else
  {
    coverage_matrix<- sampl
  }
```

Here `co_nodes` is the coverage variable. There are two loops the main loop runs 10000 times and the loop inside depends upon coverage variable. Is there any way to remove loops and speed things up.
Once the loops are processed, it is converted into a 10000*10000 matrix.The input is in the following format

```
V1 V2
33853   33842
33853   33848
33853   33852
33853   34702
33842   33839
33842   33843
33842   33848
33842   33853
33842   34696
33848   33842
33848   33849
33848   33853
33852   33740
33852   33853
33852   34703
34702   33853
34702   34701
34702   34703
33839   33816
33839   33837
```

And the output is in the form of 01 matrix 10000*10000

```
   179 181 182 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 294 419 423
179 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
181 1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
182 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
280 0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
281 0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
282 0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
283 0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
284 0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0
285 0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
286 0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0
287 0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
294 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
419 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
423 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Your `gc()` is useless if you put it after the ``return``. Please provide a minimal example that reproduce the problem (this code is too complicated).

Comment: yes i know 'gc()'  is useless i was trying different things might have placed it there. Problem is simple we are given a two column matrix  which defines connection between nodes and then from this we have to generate 0,1 matrix from it with only one factor to consider coverage. Coverage means lets say if coverage is 2 then from node 1 you can reach its neighbors and their neighbors so there will be 1 under all the nodes in 0,1 matrix which a node can reach.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you are coding your own algorithm to find connected subgraphs of a graph. This is a common problem, I would recommend finding an existing optimized solution rather than coding your own. Start with the `igraph` package.

Comment: As for your performance, using `rbind` inside a loop is terrible practice. Pre-allocate your matrix, or if you don't know how big it will be, pre-allocate a certain amount, say 10k rows, and stick on another 10k rows as needed.

Comment: I was not able to find anything like this that is why i started to write my own. The thing is in second is totally dependent on coverage variable if coverage variable is too high like 10-15 so for every node it has to run 10-15 times to pull out the neighbors it can reach. That is my biggest problem if there is a way to avoid that loop then speed can be increased significantly.

Comment: You should use `igraph`. Read through the manual, it does most common graph/network stuff. If your goal is that adjacency matrix, then `as_adj(your_graph)` will do it. Also has the option to output a sparse matrix, which might be a good idea given your size. Most `igraph` functions are implemented in C or C++ so it will be super fast. You can also split into connected subgraphs with `clusters` and `decompose`, which sounds more like your description but doesn't look like your sample output.